# Why this is giving different month

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-framework

The following code below:

```
var unixDate = new Date('07/28/2010');
    var unixMonth = unixDate.getMonth();
    var unixDay = unixDate.getDate();
    var unixYear = unixDate.getFullYear();
    alert(filterDate.value);
    alert(unixMonth);
    alert(unixDay);
    alert(unixYear);
```

should give me month 07 but it alerts 06.... why's that?

Comment: Maybe month one is 0 so December would be 11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Months are zero based. Just do `+1`. See also [`Date.getMonth()` at MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date/getMonth):

> The value returned by getMonth is an integer between 0 and 11. 0 corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

The months are 0-based, 0=January

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getMonth.asp

Answer (score 3):

`.getMonth` returns a zero indexed month. So, 0 = January, and 11 = December.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
var unixMonth = unixDate.getMonth() + 1;
```

`.getMonth` returns a zero indexed month.

```
0  = January
11 = December
```

[More Info](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getMonth.asp)

> The getMonth() method returns the
>   month (from 0 to 11) for the specified
>   date, according to local time.
>
> Note: January is 0, February is 1, and
>   so on.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that 0 = January and thus your enumeration is slightly off.